# How to test Rails 3.1/HTML5 required fields with Cucumber/Capybara?

Tags: html, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capybara

How do I check the "Please fill out this field" message that appears above required fields when they're submitted empty?

Right now my cucumber scenario seems to ignore the empty field completely, submitting the form successfully.

(I'm validating the fields presence, and when submitting manually, the form does show the message)

Comment: What Capybara driver are you using? (e.g. mechanize, selenium)

Comment: Just checking, but is there a validates_presence_of on the field, and it's still being accepted on submit?

Comment: @AndyWaite the default, from looking at the capybara README just now it looks like it's :rack_test. and it doesn't support javascript, which I didn't expect. so the answer would be to use a js driver?

Comment: @Tonys there is, and when submitting manually the message appears.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't rely on JavaScript as far as I know. I think the problem is simply that rack-test doesn't understand HTML5 yet. However, if the message appears when submitting manually but not via Cucumber then I suspect there is a bug in your test somewhere.

Comment: (continued) Try an alternative driver such as Mechanize or Selentium to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a javascript based alert, you need to use something like the :selenium driver.

```
# Set selenium as the default driver for javascript
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

# Register chrome browser for the :selenium driver
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

In doing so and tagging your scenario with `@javascript`, simply using a step like `Then I should see "Please fill out this field"` should work.

[I have a gist up that summarizes using :selenium, :capybara-webkit, headless gem for both development and continuous integration](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/5937888).  It might be helpful for your setup, but it also may be more than you are looking for at the moment.